# How do I access the text file and take out only the name and department to put into my list?

Tags: python, list

this is the question that I need to solve:

> Construct the function read_workers that receives as argument the filename
> “workers.txt”. The file contains the worker's name, surname, and department.
> The function must read the file and return two lists. The first list contains the names and
> the second list contains the department where each employee works. Order must be
> preserved.

this is the text document:

```
Name: Richard White
Department: Marketing

Name: Jane Oliver
Department: Research

Name: Kim Note
Department: Human Resources

Name: John Lee
Department: Human Resources

Name: Jennifer Six
Department: Production

Name: Maria Cruz
Department: Production
```

this is what I have:

```
def read_workers(filename):
    names = []
    departments = []
    
    with open(filename) as file:
        text = file.read()
        for line in text:
            
    return names, departments
```

im not quire sure how to proceed, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `for line in text:` is looping over each character, not lines. Either change `file.read()` to `file.readlines()`, or use `for line in file:`.

Comment: Then check if the line starts with `Name:` or `Department:`, and append the rest of the line to the appropriate list.

Comment: Don't forget to use `line.strip()` to remove the newline at the end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

1. First, `readlines()` instead of `read()` because `readlines()` give
   you a list of all the lines. (As suggested by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)
2. Second, You need to check which lines contain names and which
   departments. Then append them to their respective list.
3. Third, you need to replace "Name: " with nothing so that it won't be
   added to the list and you will only have names. Same with the
   department.

```
def read_workers(filename):
    names = []
    departments = []
    
    with open(filename) as file:
        text = file.readlines()
        for line in text:
            if line.startswith("Name"):
                names.append(line.replace("Name: ", ""))
            elif line.startswith("Department:"):
                departments.append(line.replace("Department: ", ""))

    return names, departments
```

Comment: Thanks! I inputted the suggestions of both of you and got it. However, I would like to ask some things,

1. using with open(filename, 'r'), why does this read lines instead of characters? If I want to read characters or words or lines, how can I tell the code exactly what I want to read?

Comment: `open(filename, 'r')` just opens the file, `file.read()` or `file.readlines()` actually does the reading part. The first one reads the whole file as one large string so looping over a string basically loops over each character. `f.readlines()` will read the whole file with each line as an item in a list. So looping over the list basically means you are looping over each line. And, There is no direct way to loop on words.

Answer (score 0):

Given the *"possibly chaotic"* nature of your data, I would consider approaching this with regular expressions. However frightening they might look at first glance, they are a very useful tool as a developer. You can go here to read more about them: https://regex101.com/

```py
import re

def read_workers(filename):

    with open(filename) as file:
        text = file.read()
        names = [
            i[0] for i in
            re.findall(r'[nN]ame:\s+((\w+\s+)+)', text)
        ]
        departments = [
            i[0] for i in
            re.findall(r'[dD]epartment:\s+((\w+\s+)+)', text)
        ]

    return names, departments
```